# Invalid entrypoint with aws-lambda-runtime-interface-emulator (RIE) with custom Docker image

Tags: docker, aws-lambda

I am trying to run the [AWS lambda runtime interface emulator (RIE)](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-runtime-interface-emulator) on the [following ML AWS sample](https://github.com/aws-samples/zero-administration-inference-with-aws-lambda-for-hugging-face)

I am having trouble with an invalid entrypoint

My steps are:

1. build image `docker build -t sentiment:latest .`
2. run image

Run image:

```bash
docker run -v ~/.aws-lambda-rie:/aws-lambda -p 9000:8080 --platform linux/amd64 \
    --entrypoint /aws-lambda/aws-lambda-rie \
    sentiment:latest \
        /usr/local/bin/python -m awslambdaric sentiment.handler
```

I get the following error after trying to fire a curl request `curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{"payload":"hello world!"}'` at the image:

```
13 Jul 2023 14:36:13,753 [INFO] (rapid) extensionsDisabledByLayer(/opt/disable-extensions-jwigqn8j) -> stat /opt/disable-extensions-jwigqn8j: no such file or directory
13 Jul 2023 14:36:13,753 [INFO] (rapid) Configuring and starting Operator Domain
13 Jul 2023 14:36:13,753 [INFO] (rapid) Starting runtime domain
13 Jul 2023 14:36:13,753 [WARNING] (rapid) Cannot list external agents error=open /opt/extensions: no such file or directory
13 Jul 2023 14:36:13,753 [INFO] (rapid) Starting runtime without AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SESSION_TOKEN , Expected?: false
13 Jul 2023 14:36:13,754 [WARNING] (rapid) First fatal error stored in appctx: Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint
13 Jul 2023 14:36:13,754 [ERROR] (rapid) Init failed InvokeID= error=fork/exec /usr/local/bin/python: no such file or directory
13 Jul 2023 14:36:13,755 [INFO] (rapid) Starting runtime domain
13 Jul 2023 14:36:13,756 [WARNING] (rapid) Cannot list external agents error=open /opt/extensions: no such file or directory
13 Jul 2023 14:36:13,756 [INFO] (rapid) Starting runtime without AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SESSION_TOKEN , Expected?: false
13 Jul 2023 14:36:13,756 [WARNING] (rapid) Omitting fatal error Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint: Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint already stored
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was there is no `/usr/local/bin/python` in the container it uses `python3` using python3 in the run command fixed the problem